# Is it mathematical correct proof? Need rigorous proof of uniformly tight sequence.

Tags: convergence-divergence, proof-verification

I need to prove that

> $P(\|X_n\| > M_n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ for every $M_n \to \infty$

leads to

> $P(\|X_n\| > M) < \varepsilon $ for every $N \leq n$

I do the following:

I say that it is obvious that mostly for any $i$:
$M_i<M_{i+1}$, where $i=1,\ldots,\infty$
That is why the probabilities for different values of $M$ obey this inequality: 
$$P(\|X_n\| > M_i) > P(\|X_n\| > M_{i+1}) > \cdots > 0$$

> Hence, we can state that there exist some $\varepsilon$ for which there
>   exist $M$ such that using it, $\varepsilon$ can be chosen such that
>   $P(\|X_n\| > M) < \varepsilon $

But I think this ***Hence, we can state...*** is not really mathematical proof. Which steps mathematically are omitted by me for this proof to be mathematically correct? Really do not want to skip any step and want to make this proof as meticulous as possible.

Comment: A statement that $\text{“}\varepsilon$ can be chosen such that $P(\cdots\cdots)<\varepsilon\text{''}$ is trivially true, since one could choose $\varepsilon=2$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: that is nice remark!

Comment: The point of the remark is that you should edit your question to say 'leads to for all $\epsilon>0$ and for all $M>0$ there exists $N$ such that if $n \ge N$ then...'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean that "for all $\epsilon>0$" (instead of "there exists some $\epsilon>0$"), there exists some $M$ such that $\mathbb{P}(\Vert X_n\Vert >M)<\epsilon$ for large enough $n$? Because otherwise the proof is pretty simple, just pick $\epsilon=2$

---

A possible proof is by contradiction. Suppose that

> Hence, we can state that there exist some $\epsilon>0$ for which there exist $M$ such that there is some $N$ such that $n\geq N\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(\Vert X_n \Vert >M)<ϵ$

is false. Then, there is a certain $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $M$, for all $n$, there is $k\geq n$ such that $\mathbb{P}(\Vert X_k \Vert >M)\geq ϵ$

Then, we construct recursively the following sequence $M_n$. $M_1=1$, and, for $M_n$, let
\begin{equation}
M_{n+1}=\begin{cases}
M_{n} & \text{if $\mathbb{P}(\Vert X_n\Vert>M_n)<\epsilon$}\\
M_{n}+1 & \text{if $\mathbb{P}(\Vert X_n\Vert>M_n)\geq\epsilon$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
First, we prove that $M_n\rightarrow \infty$. For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we already have that, for $M_n$, there is some $k\geq n$ such that $\mathbb{P}(\Vert X_k\Vert>M_n)>\epsilon$. Then we have $M_{k+1}=M_k+1$. This proves the sequence diverges to infinity.

Second, since for all $n$, there is some $k\geq n$ such that $\mathbb{P}(\Vert X_k\Vert>M_n)>\epsilon$ we note we can extract a subsequence $k_n$ such that $\mathbb{P}(\Vert X_{k_n} \Vert>M_{k_n})\geq\epsilon$. This contradicts that

> $\mathbb{P}(\Vert X_n\Vert>M_n)\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ for every $M_n\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: Dear Nate River, sorry for confusing, you are right. The tasks sounds like this: for every $\epsilon>0$ there exist $M$ and $N$  such that $P(...) <\epsilon$ for every $n>=N$

Comment: I think that there is a mistake in a line: is false. Then, there is a certain ..... $\mathbb{P}(\Vert X_k \Vert >M)<ϵ$ . Here must be $\mathbb{P}(\Vert X_k \Vert >M)>ϵ$ as you even call this when you prove first part. Yes?

Comment: Indeed. I just edited this.